# How to modifiy the system apps running on my phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to modify the system apps running on my specific phone. I am stumped about some important steps on how to do that - see my questions further below.

**N.B.**: I am not interested in deploying these modifications to other phones. Instead I want to play with the original code and improve it. Hence "create your own system app" is no sufficient answer.

### Background

I am just starting to get into Android development (have sufficient Java knowledge, though). There are plenty of great tutorials out there (e.g. [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html)) but they all seem to cover user application development. I'm more interested in getting (a little) "closer to the metal". Unfortunately I am unable to find good sources teaching how to do that.

### Example

As an example let's say I want to modify how the built-in brightness control works (e.g. changing the minimum) or want to add features to the call screen (e.g. "Send SMS instead" when the line is busy).

### Specific Questions

I obviously need these things to get started...

#### Sources

The sources for (parts of?) the OS running on my phone. This is the part that confuses me the most. Can I just [download the official sources](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) or is it likely that my vendor made modifications?

In my specific scenario (I use a [Fairphone](https://fairphone.com/)), could those modifications be contained in any of these sources:

- [some core apps](https://github.com/Kwamecorp/Fairphone) deployed by the vendor
- the [image binaries](https://fairphone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201189497-Fairphone-OS-multiple-versions-) (some way down the page)
- [sources for the Linux kernel and some other libraries](https://fairphone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201576803-Fairphone-Source-Code-Packages)

#### Tools

I really hope to stay in Java-land. But either case I need a development (I hope to use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) or [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html)) and a debugging environment (I hope the [Android Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) suffice).

Is it a valid assumption that I can use those tools for system apps or are they usually implemented in C?

#### Process

Assuming I can download the official sources and get started with, e.g. Android Studio. As opposed to developing a user app, do I have to do anything special to emulate the modified system app on AVD?

I'm asking because I assume that AVD already runs an unmodified version of that very app.

Comment: Try downloading the android source code. "Where do I start?" is not a programming question though.

Comment: I know this borders on not being a programming question (or might already have crossed that line). I hope it get's answered anyway. Downloading the sources does not help me as I still don't know whether this is the code which actually runs on my phone.

Comment: It doesn't border, it's blatantly not a programming question. Read books like Pro Android, then come back with specific questions. You can't expect us to write you a 5000 page explanation on how to do this.

Comment: To make things easier I removed the generic headline (you know it was a headline, right?) and added some question marks to rephrase my problems as questions. I don't see why answering them (e.g. with "your vendor might very well have edited the source; none of your links are likely to contain that modification; ADT and AVD will work, this link explains how to do it with system apps") will require 5000 pages.

Comment: Q&A only works if you ask specific questions. "How can I do that" is so broad that there's no point to answering it. You don't need an IDE, you can do everything in a basic text editor like notepad. If I say "type the code into the files then compile" I'm technically not wrong but it's completely useless as an answer. You're not asking for programming help, you're asking us to do a full blown investigation into this subject which you should really be doing yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69384/discussion-between-nicolai-parlog-and-g-v).

Comment: Seeing as you updated the question: Yes, yes, yes, most apps are written in java except for kernel related things and low level libraries that needs to be fast, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just starting to get into Android development (have sufficient Java knowledge, though). ... I'm more interested in getting (a little) "closer to the metal".

You can of course follow your own bliss, but you may find it pretty frustrating to learn Android development by hacking on the OS itself. You'll find yourself doing a lot of OS debugging and working with harder-to-use tools than normal.

> Example
>
> As an example let's say I want to modify how the built-in brightness control works (e.g. changing the minimum)

I realize this is just an example, but this could be a tough one, because there are a lot of things that contribute to brightness control -- there's the app with the UI that sets it, but that talks to the framework and ultimately the driver for the hardware that actually deals with brightness curves for the display, in coordination with the ambient light sensor.

> or want to add features to the call screen (e.g. "Send SMS instead" when the line is busy).

There's a dialer app, but implementing a feature like that will be...difficult, provided it's even feasible. I don't know offhand whether that sort of call state is available to the API.

> Specific Questions
>
> I obviously need these things to get started...
>
> Sources
>
> The sources for (parts of?) the OS running on my phone. This is the part that confuses me the most. Can I just download the official sources or is it likely that my vendor made modifications?

If you're replacing system apps, you'll need to run an OS signed with debug keys; you don't have access to the signing keys for the installed system apps on a retail build of the OS that would enable you to replace them. That will mean either getting a debug-keys installation or building it yourself from source, and flashing it to your phone. I would most strongly discourage you from using your daily phone for this sort of work -- you don't want it to be bricked when you need to receive an important call.

If you're not running a Nexus phone, then yes, your vendor has made modifications. The system apps are probably modified, and you almost certainly won't have access to the closed source of those apps. Also, there will be closed-source device drivers that are essential to the operation of the OS that you won't have access to. If you're trying to get AOSP Android up and running on such a device, as an individual hacker it's at best very, very difficult. If you're willing to use something like CyanogenMod, you could look to see if (and to what extent) they support your hardware.

If you are running a Nexus phone, then it's a goal of the AOSP project to try to have the OS bootable on select Nexus devices, though you won't necessarily enjoy the fullest functionality of the retail OS build, depending on the state of drivers -- even Nexus phones can have closed-source drivers and bits that make life more, um, exciting for building with AOSP.

> In my specific scenario (I use a Fairphone), could those modifications be contained in any of these sources:
>
> some core apps deployed by the vendor

Almost certainly

> the image binaries (some way down the page)

Not sure what you mean by that

> sources for the Linux kernel and some other libraries

It's unlikely there are significant modifications to the kernel itself, though vendors sometimes do...interesting...things with system configuration. I already mentioned device drivers. Vendors also have custom implementations/modifications of some framework APIs.

> Tools

Vendor-specific tools are rare.

> I really hope to stay in Java-land. But either case I need a development (I hope to use Android Studio or Eclipse ADT) and a debugging environment (I hope the Android Virtual Devices suffice).

Much of what you want to do can probably be implemented in Java, though it depends on how close you're getting to the hardware which can be difficult to know.

> Is it a valid assumption that I can use those tools for system apps or are they usually implemented in C?

The "system apps" are implemented in Java, but again, you sort of have to know where the dividing line is.

> Process
>
> Assuming I can download the official sources and get started with, e.g. Android Studio. As opposed to developing a user app, do I have to do anything special to emulate the modified system app on AVD?

That's actually different, because you're dealing with an emulator system image instead of a phone image. The emulator system images are completely open source, and you can build them from AOSP.

> I'm asking because I assume that AVD already runs an unmodified version of that very app.

That's correct.

To come back to my initial point, if you read between the lines of what I'm saying, I won't tell you it's impossible, but the difficulty ranges from freakin' tough on the easy end to spend-years-of-your-life on the hard end. If you really want to proceed, your best bet may be to buy the phone that's best supported by CyanogenMod and work that angle; there's a more active developer community there to help you. I know you're more excited about trying to customize the OS than you are in making a user-space app, but you'll experience less frustration with the latter than the former.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I was afraid that this would turn out to be unrealistic. My motivation is that (A) I want to get to know the OS and (B) maybe contribute modifications to the project. As I understand you the only partly realistic way out is to focus on (A) and play with the AOSP source, build my own version and use the [generated emulator](https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html#emulate-an-android-device) to test it. PS: I'll wait until Sunday for more answer before accepting.

Comment: The emulator has its own problems, but will leave you less vulnerable to forces outside your control than trying to develop for real hardware. Once you cut your teeth on that for a while then you can migrate to hardware, which will ultimately be more rewarding (so that you can actually *use* what you develop)

Comment: I asked about the emulator to verify that I understood you correctly. This is indeed a rocky road, mainly because of the requirements of building Android. Thanks again for your help.